# Grouping Pixels in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, drawing, pixel

I am making a drawing app, and I have a NSArray with a list of all the pixels the user forget or didn't clean, what i want is make groups of that list pixels using proximity. so i can highlight all the pixel area with a black circle. this is what i got for the moment but is not grouping well

```
   -(NSMutableArray*)orderMissingPixelsByGroups:(NSMutableArray*)missingPixels
      {
        NSMutableArray *finalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *auxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i=0; i<[missingPixels count]; i++) {

          NSValue *value = [missingPixels objectAtIndex:i];
          if (i<[missingPixels count]-1) {
           NSValue *nextValue = [missingPixels objectAtIndex:i+1];
           CGPoint point  = value.CGPointValue;
           CGPoint point2 = nextValue.CGPointValue;
           if (abs(point.x-point2.x)<5 ) {
             [auxArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
           }
           else if (abs(point.y-point2.y)<5){
            [auxArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
           }
        else
        {
            [auxArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            [finalArray addObject:auxArray];
            auxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        [auxArray addObject:value];
        [finalArray addObject:auxArray];
    }



   }
  return finalArray;
}
```

If you have advices I will very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can imagine this is not the best approach. Try doing something like this. Note I did not test it also there is just too much room for optimizing this approach but I hope it will help you get a bit better understanding on how to create "blobs". Otherwise you can try to search for some fast approach under "blob" keyword...

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createBlobsFromPixels:(NSMutableArray *)pixels {
    NSMutableArray *initialBlobs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSValue *pixel in pixels)
    {
        [initialBlobs addObject:@[pixel]];
    }

    while (YES) {
        NSIndexSet *indexSet = [self joinBlobs:initialBlobs minimumRadius:5.0f];
        if(indexSet.count < 2) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            [self mergeBlobs:initialBlobs atIndexA:indexSet.firstIndex andIndexB:indexSet.lastIndex];
        }
    }

    return initialBlobs;
}

- (NSIndexSet *)joinBlobs:(NSMutableArray *)blobs minimumRadius:(CGFloat)minRadius {
    // this method will try to join 2 blobs
    // if successfull it will return an index set with 2 blob indices which should be joined
    // if no blobs are able to join the method will return nil

    if(blobs.count < 2) {
        // can not join a single blub
        return nil;
    }

    NSUInteger count = blobs.count;
    // iterate through every pair
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<count-1; i++) {
        for(NSUInteger j=i+1; j<count; j++)  {
            NSArray *blobA = blobs[i];
            NSArray *blobB = blobs[j];

            // check if any of the pixels from blob A are close enough from any pixel in blob B and merge those two blobs

            for(NSValue *pixelA in blobA) {
                for(NSValue *pixelB in blobB) {
                    CGPoint pointA = [pixelA CGPointValue];
                    CGPoint pointB = [pixelB CGPointValue];
                    if(fabsf(pointA.x-pointB.x)<minRadius && fabsf(pointA.y-pointB.y)<minRadius) {
                        // can join these 2 blobs
                        NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
                        [indexSet addIndex:i];
                        [indexSet addIndex:j];
                        return indexSet; // returns YES as the blob can been joined
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)mergeBlobs:(NSMutableArray *)blobs atIndexA:(NSUInteger)indexA andIndexB:(NSUInteger)indexB {
    NSArray *blobA = blobs[indexA];
    NSArray *blobB = blobs[indexB];

    [blobs removeObject:blobA];
    [blobs removeObject:blobB];

    [blobs addObject:[blobA arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:blobB]];
}
```